# Aws elastic beanstalk nginx config is not working for my nodejs web application

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am using amazon elastic beanstalk for my nodejs website with nginx as proxy. I want to set the maximum upload size to 20mb as the default size is 1mb. I have tried all possible ways of setting up client_max_body_size in .ebextensions/.config file. But none seem to be working as i still get the 413 error. Below is my config file

---

```
container_commands:
  01_reload_nginx:
    command: "sudo service nginx reload"

files:
  "/etc/nginx/conf.d/proxy.conf" :
    mode: "000644"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
       client_max_body_size 20M;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `/etc/nginx/conf.d/proxy.conf` is for **Amazon Linux 1** (AL1). However, you may be using current version of EB (not specified in the question), which is  **Amazon Linux 2** (AL2).

For AL2, you should use [the config files](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/platforms-linux-extend.html) in `.platform/nginx/conf.d/`.

There are **many differences** between AL1 and AL2 in EB:

- [How do I migrate my Elastic Beanstalk environment from one AWS account to another AWS account?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/elastic-beanstalk-migration-accounts/)

Thus you may need to modify extra files to make your application work if you are migrating it from AL1 to AL2.

Comment: You are a saviour! This worked like a charm! So much time wasted over a silly mistake! Thank you!! Im running AL2 and configuring nginx in .platform did the trick!

Comment: I am trying to set my clent_max_body_size setting for nginx also.  I think I put it into the right folder, could you post what your final configuration file looks like?

Comment: @J.Chaney Maybe it would be a good idea to make new question specific to your setup and error messages if any?

Comment: @Marcin I did, but, I would like to know if I setup my conf.d file correctly and looking at an example would help.  I've searched for examples online.  I think my example matches, but, I'm still having issues.  I have created a separate question about my issue specifically though.

Comment: [This link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.migration-al.html) is more relevant

Answer (score 0):

For Elastic Beanstalk - Amazon Linux 2:

Create `.platform/nginx/conf.d/client_max_body_size.conf` in the application root folder.

Add one line to the file: `client_max_body_size    20M;`

Deploy your code.